# Total eligible days

Tags: sql, oracle

There is 1 table wherein all these records are maintained for 1 employee. I want to get the total number of days as output for the time person was eligible in each job with the latest row of each job. Eligibility is stored in Eligible column as Y  value wherein Y value means the row is eligible. I am able to extract the latest row in each job through lead function but now how to get the total number of days with the eligibility rule.
Please help me.

```
StDt          EdDt           Eligible   Job   
01-Jan-21     31-Jan-21      Y          J1   
01-Jul-21     31-Jul-21      Y          J1    
01-Aug-21     31-Aug-21      Y          J2
```

Output Should be :

```
StDt          EdDt           Eligible   Job      TotalDays    
01-Jul-21     31-Jul-21      Y          J1       62    
01-Aug-21     31-Aug-21      Y          J2       31
```

Comment: When you share your sample data with us, all the data is presented as text (strings). However, in computing (and in particular in a database), "data" has "data type", which may be "text" or a lot of other things, and knowing the data type is crucial. In your case, what is the data type of `StDt` and `EdDt`? It should be `date` - but very often (and very wrong) people store dates in text data type (as strings). Run `describe TABLENAME` (replace `TABLENAME` with the actual table name) and see what it says about the data type of your columns, and include that in your question.

Comment: Also: Do you have just one employee? Or does the table contain data for many employees (perhaps distinguished by an employee id, in another column you didn't share with us)? If so, does the query need to run for a single employee, when you give an id as input, or do you need the computation to run for all employees, returning one row per employee id?

Comment: I have more than 1 employee but I will amend it later on..you can revert for multiple employee or 1 employee..I can reuse the code.

Comment: Why do you expect `01-Jul-21 | 31-Jul-21` for Job J1? What about January?

Answer (score 0):

Just `SUM` the difference between the dates when eligible (and add 1 to include the entirety of the final day of each range):

```
SELECT SUM(EdDt-StDt+1) AS num_eligible_days
FROM   table_name
WHERE  eligible = 'Y';
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (StDt, EdDt, Eligible) AS
SELECT DATE '2021-01-01', DATE '2021-01-31', 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-02-01', DATE '2021-06-30', 'N' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-07-01', DATE '2021-07-31', 'Y' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | NUM_ELIGIBLE_DAYS |
> | --- |
> | 62 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3b27a304154b475e0458524f5b7213f6)*

---

#### After the Question Changed

```sql
SELECT Job,
       SUM(EdDt-StDt+1) AS num_eligible_days
FROM   table_name
WHERE  eligible = 'Y'
GROUP BY Job;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (StDt, EdDt, Eligible, Job) AS
SELECT DATE '2021-01-01', DATE '2021-01-31', 'Y', 'J1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-02-01', DATE '2021-06-30', 'N', 'J1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-07-01', DATE '2021-07-31', 'Y', 'J1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-08-01', DATE '2021-08-31', 'Y', 'J2' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | JOB | NUM_ELIGIBLE_DAYS |
> | --- | --- |
> | J2 | 31 |
> | J1 | 62 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=80c2c9276ce1b4c0a1ee870294af668e)*

Comment: Hey I was editing the question. I am not sure if your solution will help me now.

Comment: I assume you missed `GROUP BY eligible, Job`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit No, the OP edited the question after I answered it.

Comment: That's what I expected.